# Application of Phaser from java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have been going through java concurrency topics and have understood the real time applications of Semaphore,CountDownLatch,CyclicBarrier and Exchange classes. I am trying to understand the usage of Phaser in realtime scenario but haven't yet got the information. Have searched online as well but couldn't get the relevant information. Can anyone please advise on the realtime application of Phaser or if you could provide me a link to relevant article if any.

I have already asked the question in the forum https://coderanch.com/t/693964/java/Application-Phaser-java-util-concurrent but did not get response as of now.

Comment: The class documentation gives examples of using Phasers. What about the documentation are you having a problem with?

Comment: By googling "java.util.concurrent Phaser", I found many articles and tutorials, including [this nice one](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/phaser.html). Did you really look that hard?